# How to delete entity in many-to-many relationship using POCOs

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, many-to-many, poco

I'm using POCOs in combination with EF4 and some entities are in many-to-many relationships, in my case objects of class User and objects of class PrivilegeGroup.

This is how class User looks like:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { set; get; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public List<PrivilegeGroup> PrivilegeGroups { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how class PrivilegeGroup looks like:

```
public class PrivilegeGroup
{
    public int PrivilegeGroupID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public List<HasPrivilege> HasPrivileges { get; set; }
}
```

I have extended ObjectContext class
as follows:

```
public class AdminMDSContext : ObjectContext
{

    public AdminMDSContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)

    {
        this.DefaultContainerName = "MDSUsers_Entities";
        _users = CreateObjectSet<User>();
        _privilegeGroups = CreateObjectSet<PrivilegeGroup>();

    }


    private ObjectSet<User> _users;
    private ObjectSet<PrivilegeGroup> _privilegeGroups;

    public ObjectSet<User> Users
    {
        get { return _users; }
    }


    public ObjectSet<PrivilegeGroup> PrivilegeGroups
    {
        get { return _privilegeGroups; }
        set { _privilegeGroups = value; }
    }

}
```

Querying and insertion of these entities are working fine, but deletion is making problem, i.e. I want to remove PrivilegeGroup from one User without db roundtrip, but I don't know how to do it.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What have you tried? It seems to me that `yourUser.PrivilegeGroups.Remove(yourPrivilegeGroup)`; context.SaveChanges();` should do the job, but I might be wrong. Can you please show some code on what you've tried to actually perform the delete?

Comment: using (AdminMDSContext context = new AdminMDSContext(GetConnStringHTMLDecoded()))
{
var usVar = from us in context.Users
     where us.UserID == userId
     select us;
User user = usVar.SingleOrDefault<User>();
var pgVar = from pg in context.PrivilegeGroups
    where pg.PrivilegeGroupID == privilegeGroupId
    select pg;
PrivilegeGroup privilegeGroup = pgVar.SingleOrDefault<PrivilegeGroup>();

if (user.PrivilegeGroups == null)
{user.PrivilegeGroups = new List<PrivilegeGroup>();}
user.PrivilegeGroups.Add(privilegeGroup);
user.PrivilegeGroups.Remove(privilegeGroup);
context.SaveChanges();
}

Comment: well, this code above definitely doesn't look promising.To cut story short, I created objects with data filtered by needed ids, for object of User class I initialized List<PrivilegeGroup> and then I added and removed from it my PrivilegeGroup object. After that, I saved changes on context. And I had two queries to database to find one User and one PrivilegeGroup and I didn't have any delete sql query. I want the opposite, just to have executed delete sql query. I don't know what am I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I solved it  with explicit loading of  List<PrivilegeGroups>, but I still have three db accesses, and I wish to have only one, which will just do needed delete sql query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. Here is how u do it.

```
var user = new User { UserId = 1 };
var admin = new Privilege { PrivilegeId = 1 };
user.Privileges.Add(admin);
db.Users.Attach(user);
user.Privileges.Remove(admin);
db.SaveChanges();
```

There are total of 4 different approaches to solving the same problem. but i think from what u are telling me, this should suffice but if u need more info, you can ping me directly through mail

Comment: Thank you very much, zeeshanhirani! There was one thing though, I had to add additional two lines:
if (user.Privileges == null) 
 user.Privileges = new List<Privilege>();

Comment: I have this same question...I'd rather not deal with the ObjectContext/ObjectSets directly. Could you elaborate on the other 3 approaches please? Thanks.